# Using laravel blade syntax when appending html using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm trying to append an image coming from the server using asset() directive inside jquery append() method.

```
               @isset($prod)
                    @if($prod->prod_images()->count() > 0)
                        @foreach($prod->prod_images()->get() as $image)
                            var image = @json($image);

                            $('.input-images').find('.uploaded').append(`
                                <div class="uploaded-image" data-index="0">
                                    <img src="${image.image}">
                                    <button class="delete-image">
                                    <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            `);
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                @endisset
```

As seen in the code, i'm able to get the image path inside the src attribute but i also wants to use the asset() directive inside the append() method.

Comment: You should be able to use `{{ asset(...) }}` with `$image` inside that code. Did you try anything? What error are you getting?

Comment: @TimLewis i guess the ${image.image} are from javascript. try using  "{{ asset('') }}${image.image}" or "{{ asset($image['image']) }}"

Comment: @AlzafanChristian Yeah, `asset()` is a PHP function, and will not work with `image` (the JS variable), but it will work with `$image` (the PHP variable). It would be `$image->image`, not `$image.image`

Comment: @TimLewis I tried both the options, none of them works for me

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and the error you got. "None of them works" is not a helpful message... Why didn't it work? Did you get any errors? Please provide as much details as possible.